# How to get a substring of this string Python3

Tags: python-3.x

string:

```
ecsdcsdcsdfvdfv":"https://scdsscdcsdent-mxp1-1.cdninstdscsdcagdssdcsdam.com/v/t51.283485-19/s320x320/79000872_1455436197941341_7513464347075543040_n.pnk?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp1-1.cdninadcdcdm.codcsdcm&_nc_ohc=0fehqjedb48AX8r72Hi&oh=eb1f6a78a2dcd67e443aa7f74eee91b4&oe=5E7F0A0C","vsvdfvsfvcfvfdcvfd
```

substring that i want to get:

```
https://scdsscdcsdent-mxp1-1.cdninstdscsdcagdssdcsdam.com/v/t51.283485-19/s320x320/79000872_1455436197941341_7513464347075543040_n.pnk?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp1-1.cdninadcdcdm.codcsdcm&_nc_ohc=0fehqjedb48AX8r72Hi&oh=eb1f6a78a2dcd67e443aa7f74eee91b4&oe=5E7F0A0C
```

i tried this but doesn't work

```
print (log.split("ecsdcsdcsdfvdfv",1)[1])
```

Comment: Why not just parse it as json and take the value?

Comment: @Guimoute i tried your split, it doesn't work

Comment: @Sayse if you find a simple solution using json.parse i'll follow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This yield the expected result.

The way you used `.split()` was wrong, you did not include the `"` character.

```
string = 'ecsdcsdcsdfvdfv":"https://scdsscdcsdent-mxp1-1.cdninstdscsdcagdssdcsdam.com/v/t51.283485-19/s320x320/79000872_1455436197941341_7513464347075543040_n.pnk?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp1-1.cdninadcdcdm.codcsdcm&_nc_ohc=0fehqjedb48AX8r72Hi&oh=eb1f6a78a2dcd67e443aa7f74eee91b4&oe=5E7F0A0C","vsvdfvsfvcfvfdcvfd'
substring = string.split('ecsdcsdcsdfvdfv":"')[1].split('","vsvdfvsfvcfvfdcvfd')[0]
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for! Thanks

Comment: you forgot a " on the start

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```py
log.split('":"')[1].split('","')[0]
```

But this is not the best way to do what you are trying to achieve. Better parse it and get what you want.

Comment: That won't give the expected output though

Comment: I know :) Edited

Comment: I don't like this solution because i i got a string with more ":" it doesn't work

Comment: More ":"? What do you mean? :D

Comment: int the start and in the end of the string more ":"

Comment: So what's the condition for splitting? Do you need to split between first ":" and the last ",", or the one in the middle? or what?

Comment: this was the same good, but you edited it after a while (i upvoted you)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the string between the `":"` and `","`, then you can use regular expression to do it.

```py
re.match('(.*\":\")([^\",\"]*)(\",\".*)', log).group(2)
```

Given your input

```
'ecsdcsdcsdfvdfv":"https://scdsscdcsdent-mxp1-1.cdninstdscsdcagdssdcsdam.com/v/t51.283485-19/s320x320/79000872_1455436197941341_7513464347075543040_n.pnk?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp1-1.cdninadcdcdm.codcsdcm&_nc_ohc=0fehqjedb48AX8r72Hi&oh=eb1f6a78a2dcd67e443aa7f74eee91b4&oe=5E7F0A0C","vsvdfvsfvcfvfdcvfd'
```

you will get

```
'https://scdsscdcsdent-mxp1-1.cdninstdscsdcagdssdcsdam.com/v/t51.283485-19/s320x320/79000872_1455436197941341_7513464347075543040_n.pnk?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp1-1.cdninadcdcdm.codcsdcm&_nc_ohc=0fehqjedb48AX8r72Hi&oh=eb1f6a78a2dcd67e443aa7f74eee91b4&oe=5E7F0A0C'
```

And if you input something like

```
'ecsdcsdcs":"dfvdfv":"https://s...F0A0C","vsvdfvsfvcfvfdc","vfd'
```

you will get

```
'https://s...F0A0C'
```

Dont forget to `import re`.